# Обработка событий оплаты сбербанка (django)

Tags: python, django

недавно начал заниматься разработкой, подскажите пожалуйста как среагировать на события завершения оплаты, подключена кнопка оплаты от сбербанка, не могу разобраться где и как на неё реагировать. По инструкции обработка должна происходить в бэкенде. На всякий случай вот ссылка на инструкцию от самого сбера. Подскажите по какому запросу искать информацию? https://securepayments.sberbank.ru/wiki/doku.php/integration:paybutton:start. Заранее огромное  спасибо

views.py:

```
 def get_data(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            usr_id = request.user.client.id
        else:
            usr_id = 3
        passport_info = client.objects.get(id=usr_id)
        result = parsej(x=passport_info.serial, y=passport_info.number)
        if passport_info and result:
            context = {"passport_info": passport_info, "result": result}
            return render(request, "main/get_data.html", context=context)

        else:
            return render(request, "main/index.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "accounts/login.html")
```

Страница оплаты:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
<div class="container">
<h4 class="text-dark mt-2">Оплата по залоговому билету</h4>
<h6 class="text-dark">Перед оплатой просьба сверить серию и номер паспорта: </h6>
<h6 class="text-danger">{{passport_info.serial}} {{passport_info.number}}</h6>
 <hr size="5" color="#36E052" />
</div>

 <div class="container">
 {% for el in result %}

  <table class="table sm table-hover">
 <tbody>
   <tr >
  <td style="font-size: 16px"> <h6>Залоговый билет номер №: {{el.Залог}}</h6></td>
  <td style="font-size: 16px">Сумма к оплате: {{el.СуммаПроцентов}}</td>
<td style="font-size: 16px"><a onclick="ipayCheckout({
amount:'{{el.СуммаПроцентов}}',
currency:'RUB',
order_number:'{{el.Залог}}',
description: '{{el.Залог}}'},
function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },
function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })"
 
class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Оплатить</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

{% endfor %}
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Примерная функция:

```
def successCallback(order):<br>
    response = requests.get('https://3dsec.sberbank.ru/payment/rest/getOrderStatusExtended.do?', params={'userName': 'T5609192428-api', 'password': 'T5609192428', 'orderNumber': order})<br>
    content=response.json()<br>
    result=content['orderNumber']<br>
    result2=content['amount']<br>
    content={"Номер залогового билета": result, "Оплаченная сумма": result2}<br>
    return content<br>
    print(content)<br>
```

Comment: какой именно вариант вам нужен?

Comment: Я написал пример функции по проверке оплаты, но не понимаю как и куда её разместить. В документации указано, что после проведения оплаты, вызывается функция successCallback, в данный момент я её написал и она работает, но не вызывается автоматически, куда бы я её не размещал. Пример функции в конце вопроса

Comment: обратитесь в тех поддержку сбера, скорее всего надо где указать callback url